# Inserting a string formed of variables into an MSSQL database using VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, insert

I have a database with a table called LaptopTrolleyWU that has the following structure: 
ComputerName      *varchar(50)*
TimeStamp      *datetime*
Log      *varchar(MAX)*

I am trying to insert text into the Log field from a VBScript script, but cannot work out the syntax in order to do so.

This is what I have so far:

```
 For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & _
        ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode   
        objFile.WriteLine(I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode)    
Connection.Execute "INSERT INTO LaptopTrolleyWU (Log) VALUES ('" & I + 1 & "'>  '" & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & "':  '" & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode & "')"
Next
End If
```

I get an error that reads

> 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server][Incorrect syntax near ')'.

What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, this is how I originally connect to the DB, which I might have done incorrectly...

```
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim ConnectionString
ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server;Trusted_Connection=no;Database=LaptopTrolly;Uid=Laptop;Pwd=password"
Connection.Open ConnectionString
```

Comment: What is the value of I?  Print the entire Execute statement.  What does it say?

Comment: added what you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end:

```
strLogText = I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode
        strSQLCmd = "INSERT INTO dbo.LaptopTrolleyWU (ComputerName,TimeStamp,Log) VALUES ('" + strComputerName + "', '" + dtTimeStamp + "' , '" + strLogText + "')"
        Connection.Execute strSQLCmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to write the value of a string expression into a log file and a database field (I assume the .Echo is just for debugging). Then you should invest into a variable to hold the value of the expression and use that twice:

```
v = I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode
```

Writing to a file is easy, because you just need the plain data:

```
objFile.WriteLine v
```

(no spurious param list ()!). You need an INSERT statement to put v into the database; the value of v has to be single quoted:

```
>> v = "pipapo"
>> s = Replace("INSERT INTO LaptopTrolleyWU (Log) VALUES ('@v')", "@v", v)
>> WScript.Echo s
>>
INSERT INTO LaptopTrolleyWU (Log) VALUES ('pipapo')
>>
```

If you then do

```
WScript.Echo s
Connection.Execute s
```

you can be sure that the statement you execute is the code you have visually inspected.

Your expressions differ:

```
I + 1 & "> " & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode
I + 1 & "'>  '" & updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & "':  '" & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode
```

The extra single quotes in the INSERT statement make the SQL parser assume you want to compare string literals.